# Swing: Which layout to use for a html table like behavior and how?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to display a two column layout in swing, a text label on the left and a button on the right. 80% width to be allocated to label and 20% width to be allocated to the button. Also, the number of rows are dynamic.

I have tried to use multiple layout managers, but none is working correctly. If I use the default layout, the label and the button move onto a single line if the applet is resized.
If I use BorderLayout, the size of button becomes huge.

Code snippet:

```
    this.contentPanel = new JPanel();
for (String eachParam : paramArrayList) {
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel(eachParam);
        JButton btn = new JButton();
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        btn.setText("Find");
        btn.setName(eachParam);
        pane.add(lbl);
        pane.add(btn);
        this.contentPanel.add(pane);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://java.net/projects/tablelayout

I've used it many times, great layout.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I have tried using it but it seems really confusing. Can you provide example code for preparing a n X n table using this layout?

Comment: layout = new TableLayout();

        columns = new double[3];
        rows    = new double[3];
        columns[0] = TableLayout.PREFERRED; //size of a component
        columns[1] = 50;  //50 px
        columns[2] = 0.4; //40% 
        rows[0]    = TableLayout.PREFERRED; //size of a component
        rows[0]    = 0.55; //55%
        rows[0]    = 180;  //180px line
        
        layout.setColumn(columns);
        layout.setRow(rows);
setLayout(layout);

Comment: Your code example will be more readable if you edit your question.